# Slider Revolution error codes in Chromme - Video does not play

Tags: google-chrome, slider

When trying to render slide revolution videos in wordpress, I've encountered the following errors.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?rev=5.4.8:32 ThemePunch GreenSocks Logs
jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:32 ThemePunch GreenSocks Logs
2/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/assets/svg/navigation/ic_close_24px.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/assets/svg/hardware/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24px.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'fill' of undefined
    at Function.buildFullTimeLine (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7)
    at Function.each (jquery.js?ver=1.12.4&nocache=1:2)
    at Function.animateTheCaptions (revolution.extension.layeranimation.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7)
    at swapSlideProgress (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7)
    at Object.target (jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:7)
    at Object.h._callback (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:60)
    at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:60)
    at Object.h.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:60)
    at Object.D._updateRoot.G.render (jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js?ver=5.4.8&nocache=1:60)
/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/assets/svg/hardware/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_24px.svg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Everything works perfectly in IE and Firefox.

Anyone know how to fix this?